# Memory Limit Exceeded while reading integers into the vector

Tags: c++, string, parsing, file-io, vector

I am trying to read integer values from text file into a vector.

Input file `ip1.txt` has the following content:

> 4
>
> -1000 -2000 -3000 -4000

```
int maxsub(vector<int> a, int size)
{
    a.erase(a.begin());
    vector<int> sum;
    for(vector<int>::iterator w=a.begin(); w <= a.begin()+size-1; ++w)
    {
        int j;
        int s=*w;
        for(int t=0; t <= size-1; t++)
        {
            j = s + a[t];
            sum.push_back(j);
        }
        a.pop_back();
    }
    std::sort(sum.begin(),sum.end());

    int u = sum.size()-1;
    int m = sum.at(u);
    return m;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums( (std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>() );
    int k = nums[0];
    int u = maxsub(nums,k);
    cout << u <<endl;
}
```

I am getting Warning message as 'Memory Limit Exceeded'

How can i resrict vector to read only till -4000 in the input file,I am using file redirection 
**./123 < ip1.txt **

Comment: I would use a `for` or `while` loop to read the elements one at a time till the sentinel value `-4000` ....

Comment: How big is the file? Looks to me like your code has bugs, I'm wondering is the error is caused by one of those bugs rather than the size of the file.

Comment: why `w <= a.begin()+size-1` if you can do `w < a.begin()+size`?

Comment: why `int u = sum.size()-1; int m = sum.at(u); return m;` when you can do `return sum.back();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug at the source code.
All loops in maxsub()

```
for(vector<int>::iterator w=a.begin(); w <= a.begin()+size-1; ++w)
for(int t=0; t <= size-1; t++)
```

has iterations from 0 to size-1 elements (=size all in all elements), but after code

```
a.erase(a.begin());
```

vector 'a' has only (size-1) elements.
Therefore, all for-operators is 'outside-the-boundary'.
I think, it's cause of warning message.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the first number will be the length of your vector, why not take advantage of it?:

```
int length = 0;
std::cin >> length;

std::vector<int> numbers;
numbers.reserve(length);
```

then you can just use simple `for` loop that checks whether the number has been successfully extracted from the stream and also prevents more than specific amount of numbers being read:

```
int number;
for (int i = 0; (i < length) && (std::cin >> number); ++i)
{
    numbers.push_back(number);
}
```

Don't forget to `#include <iostream>`, `#include <sstream>` and `#include <vector>`. Also note that `std::cin` can be easily replaced with file stream :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a for loop

```
std::vector<int> nums;
int size;
std::cin >> size;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    int val;
    std::cin >> val;
    nums.push_back(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'a.begin()+size-1' is before begin():

Having

```
for(vector<int>::iterator w=a.begin(); w <= a.begin()+size-1; ++w)
```

and

```
int k = nums[0];
int u = maxsub(nums,k);
```

and

```
nums[0] = -1000;
```

size is -1000

If you want to exclude the first and last element:

```
if( ! a.empty()) {
    // Not erasing the first element: a.erase(a.begin());
    for(vector<int>::size_type i = 1;  i < a.size() - 1; ++i);
}
```